# Grails internall error with new controller

Tags: grails

I just created Intellij grails app,first I opened the console and did : `grails create-app helloworld`, `cd helloworld` and  I started the app on `localhost` and everything was ok but then I opened the project with intelliJ and created a controller to print the message "hi" and build the project.

After I closed IntelliJ I went back to the terminal and tried to run the app but it gave me this error:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

- **URI**

  /testc/index
- **Class**

  javax.servlet.ServletException
- **Message**

  Could not resolve view with name '/testc/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

Answer (score 0):

Fairly impossible to answer without some example code, but generating a controller does not magically make the output appear. Your clue is in the "Could not resolve view with name..." I'd suggest a read through the grails docs. No sense repeating all that good information here.

Comment: I just put  :     def home() {
render "<h1>Real Programmer</h1>"
}      , in the controller class ,inside

Comment: "/testc/index" doesn't match anything in the web app if your controller method is named "home". if the url is testc/index, then grails will be looking for an "index" method in the controller.